# CoreUI only one dropdown at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, vue.js, core-ui

I want my sidebar dropdown to be available only one at a time, so when I click on another dropdown, the previous dropdown will be hidden again.

Below is the example of my current dropdown, which where you can open multiple dropdowns at a time. https://coreui.io/vue/demo/#/dashboard

```
<template>
  <router-link tag="li" class="nav-item nav-dropdown" :to="url" disabled>
    <div class="nav-link nav-dropdown-toggle" @click="handleClick"><i :class="icon"></i> {{name}}</div>
    <ul class="nav-dropdown-items">
      <slot></slot>
    </ul>
  </router-link>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      name: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
      },
      url: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
      },
      icon: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
      }
    },
    methods: {
      handleClick(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.target.parentElement.classList.toggle('open');
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way to make a radio-group type controller (where only one item can be selected at once) is to have a variable that indicates which one is selected. Then each element compares itself to the selected one to determine whether it should be in the open state.

Since you have multiple `router-link`s that don't know about each other, the parent object is going to have to own the which-one-is-selected indicator variable. The `handleClick` of your `router-link` should [`$emit` an event](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Emitting-a-Value-With-an-Event) that the parent will handle by changing the indicator variable. And the `router-link` should receive the indicator variable as a [prop](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-to-Child-Components-with-Props) and use it in a [computed](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) to set the `open` class as appropriate.

Your code might look like this:

```
<template>
  <router-link tag="li" class="nav-item nav-dropdown" :class="openClass" :to="url" disabled>
    <div class="nav-link nav-dropdown-toggle" @click="handleClick"><i :class="icon"></i> {{name}}</div>
    <ul class="nav-dropdown-items">
      <slot></slot>
    </ul>
  </router-link>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      name: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        selectedItem: Object
      },
      url: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
      },
      icon: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
      }
    },
    computed: {
      openClass() {
        return this.selectedItem === this ? 'open' : '';
      }
    }
    methods: {
      handleClick(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.$emit('setSelected', this);
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add "itemAttr" property in _nav.js like:

```
items: [
    {
    name: 'Dropdown',
    url: '/dropdown',
    icon: 'icon-grid',
    itemAttr: { id: 'drop-1' },
    children: [{
      name: 'Sub-Item 1',
      url: '/dropdown/subitem1'
    }, {
      name: 'Sub-Item 2',
      url: '/dropdown/subitem2'
    }, {
      name: 'Sub-Item 3',
      url: '/dashboard/subitem3'
    }]
    },
    {
      name: 'Base',
      url: '/base',
      icon: 'icon-base',
      itemAttr: { id: 'item-1' }
    }
]
```

and in DefaultLayout.js, add event-listeners for click on these two id's, like:

```
var e1 = document.getElementById("drop-1")
e1.addEventListener("click", function () {
  e1.classList.className += " open";
});   
var ev1 = document.getElementById("item-1")
ev1.addEventListener("click", function () {
  e1.className = "nav-item nav-dropdown"  
});
```

Similarly, you can add more dropdowns and give them id's "drop-2" and "drop-3". OnClick, if you want to open that dropdown list use:

```
e<i>.classList.className += " open";
```

and for all the remaining dropdowns that you want to close use:

```
e<j>.className = "nav-item nav-dropdown";
```

When clicking on an item you want to close all dropdowns, so use:

```
e<i>.className = "nav-item nav-dropdown"; //for all the dropdown items.
```